# Reason for User Account Control dialog

Tags: windows-7, uac

Can I see the reason for User Account Control dialog appearing?

When starting [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx), the UAC dialog appears. I don't see a reason why the program should need elevated privileges. Is there a way to see why the UAC dialog was launched?

Answer (score 2):

Have you reviewed the UAC event log? (Computer Management, Event Viewer, Applications and Services Logs, Microsoft, Windows, UAC, Operational)

You might try turning on [UAC Auditing](http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/how-to-configure-auditing-privilege-elevation.html).

Comment: I haven't until now. From the web site link you provided it seems that one can only see that UAC was started and not why, but I'll try it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the executable (or a .Net App Config file) has specified that it must run elevated it can do anything to the system once it is started. I would use [Microsoft Sysinternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to track its actions. Look for changes outside of the user's profile or registry key.

One common mistake is a hard coded use of the system's temp folder (C:\temp) and rather than the user's temp folder. This problem can be solved by changing the folder's permissions. However, there are many security risks to doing this.